# How to resolve "undefined reference" when linking to libjpeg on Windows?

Tags: windows, g++, cmake, mingw, libjpeg

I'm trying to build a software, which requires libfftw3f, libxml2 and libjpeg, with MinGW and CMake on Windows.

I have downloaded a compiled version of libxml2 via `mingw-get` and built libfftw3f and libjpeg from source by myself without any problem. After setting the include and library paths in the CMake GUI, the Makefile is generated and `mingw32-make` compiles all source files. But when it comes to linking the binary, I get the following error messages:

```
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x1
90): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error(jpeg_error_mgr*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x1
b4): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, uns
igned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x1
c6): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest(jpeg_compress_struct*, _iobuf*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x1
f6): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x2
0d): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x2
1d): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x2
58): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines(jpeg_compress_struct*, unsigne
d char**, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x2
66): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x2
e5): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error(jpeg_error_mgr*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
09): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int,
 unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
1b): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src(jpeg_decompress_struct*, _iobuf*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
2b): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
59): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
ff): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines(jpeg_decompress_struct*, unsign
ed char**, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x4
38): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [detect_ffld.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The mentioned file `JPEGImage.cpp` includes `jpeglib.h`.

My `link.txt` generated by CMake shows the following line:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MinGW\bin\g++.exe   -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG    -fopenmp -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o detect_ffld.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libdetect_ffld.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -LC:\ffld\fftw-3.3.4\.libs -LC:\ffld\jpeg-6b\.libs -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib" -lfftw3f -ljpeg -lxml2 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

I wondered about g++ trying to link to `jpeg_std_error`, while it turns out by running `nm libjpeg.a`, that the name of the procedure is `_jpeg_std_error` (leading underscore seems to be common for C functions on Windows). I have already tried to create a version of libjpeg without the leading underscore by running `objcopy --remove-leading-char libjpeg.a libjpeg2.a` (after that, I replaced libjpeg.a by the new libjpeg2.a, of course). But that didn't change the above output of `mingw32-make` in any way.

Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance!

---

### Edit - Additional Information

#### Relevant excerpts from CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(FFLD)

SET(HEADERS Rectangle.h JPEGImage.h Object.h Scene.h HOGPyramid.h Patchwork.h Model.h Mixture.h Intersector.h)
SET(SOURCES Rectangle.cpp JPEGImage.cpp Object.cpp Scene.cpp HOGPyramid.cpp
Patchwork.cpp Model.cpp Mixture.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(detect_ffld ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ffld.cpp)

# There are no CMake FFTW package, so find it ourselves
FIND_PATH(FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR fftw3.h)
IF(FFLD_HOGPYRAMID_DOUBLE)
  FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES fftw3)
ELSE()
  FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES fftw3f)
ENDIF()
IF(NOT FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR OR NOT FFTW3_LIBRARIES)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find fftw3.")
ENDIF()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(detect_ffld ${FFTW3_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(JPEG REQUIRED)
IF(JPEG_FOUND)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(detect_ffld ${JPEG_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
IF(LIBXML2_FOUND)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(detect_ffld ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(${LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS})
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)
IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
ENDIF()
```

Note that building this on Linux using the available libjpeg, libxml2 and libfftw3 packages works like a charm. But on Windows, I had to set the paths to the directories and libraries by myself in the CMake GUI and especially linking libjpeg is troublesome.

#### Output of `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\ffld\ffld -BC:\ffld\ffld\build
 --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 detect_ffld
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\ffld\ffld -BC:\ffld\ffld\build
 --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\ffld\ffl
d\build\CMakeFiles 9
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/all
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir
/depend
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles"
C:\ffld\ffld C:\ffld\ffld C:\ffld\ffld\build C:\ffld\ffld\build C:\ffld\ffld\bui
ld\CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir
/build
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
Linking CXX executable detect_ffld.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\det
ect_ffld.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\detect_ffld
.dir/objects.a
C:\PROGRA~2\MinGW\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles
\detect_ffld.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\PROGRA~2\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE   -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG    -fopenmp -Wl,--whole-
archive CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o detect_f
fld.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libdetect_ffld.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--mino
r-image-version,0  -LC:\ffld\fftw-3.3.4\.libs -LC:\ffld\jpeg-6b -L"C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib" -lfftw3f -ljpeg -lxml2 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32
 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x3
f0): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error(jpeg_error_mgr*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x4
16): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int,
 unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x4
22): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src(jpeg_decompress_struct*, _iobuf*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x4
32): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x4
62): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x5
00): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines(jpeg_decompress_struct*, unsign
ed char**, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x5
3a): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
20): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error(jpeg_error_mgr*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
43): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, uns
igned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
53): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest(jpeg_compress_struct*, _iobuf*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
8e): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
a9): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality(jpeg_compress_struct*, int, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
b9): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*, int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
e8): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines(jpeg_compress_struct*, unsigne
d char**, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj):JPEGImage.cpp:(.text+0x7
f5): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress(jpeg_compress_struct*)'
c:/progra~2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C
MakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir/objects.a(JPEGImage.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x64 i
n section `.text$_ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iter
atorIPhS1_EEjRKh[__ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_ite
ratorIPhS1_EEjRKh]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\detect_ffld.dir\build.make:300: recipe for target 'detect_ffld.exe' f
ailed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [detect_ffld.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:97: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/all' fail
ed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:109: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/rule' fa
iled
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/detect_ffld.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/ffld/ffld/build'
Makefile:121: recipe for target 'detect_ffld' failed
mingw32-make: *** [detect_ffld] Error 2
```

Comment: Even though the error you get mentions `jpeg_std_error`, that name has been demangled by GCC, so the linker is aware it should look for `_jpeg_std_error`. Just wondering: can't you build libjpeg as part of your project, in order to use the same flags as this?

Comment: I would have to create appropriate CMake files for libjpeg then, didn't I? It seems a litte bit complicated to port libjpeg's configure script to CMake. Or do I missunderstand you?

Comment: No, I meant exactly that. Thing is, I just wanted to be sure both libjpeg and your project had been compiled with the same options.

Comment: Okay, now I've built libjpeg with CMake within the same project, as suggested. But, unfortunately, I still get the same error messages.

Comment: And, just to rule out the obvious, you specify libjpeg among the targets to link against in `target_link_libraries`, didn't you?

Comment: can you post some of the related CMake lines and compile with `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: @Ax3l: I've added both above.

Comment: How are you including jpeglib.h?  Like this?    extern "C" {
        #include <jpeglib.h>
    }

Comment: Without `extern "C"`. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Holy... @PeterG: That was it. I really should have come up with that by myself. Please post it as an answer, so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `jpeglib.h` like this:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <jpeglib.h>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The leading underscores are not the problem.  For your lib path

```
-LC:\ffld\jpeg-6b\.libs\libjpeg.a
```

should be

```
-LC:\ffld\jpeg-6b\.libs
```

Not sure how to fix that using the CMake gui, I think you just run it again and select the directory instead of the file.  The compiler might not be complaining, because it might be finding a "jpeg.dll" in the path, and trying to link against that, which probably is not binary compatible with the version you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed that flag, but, unfortunately, the problem persists.